# Understanding edges past the body

Tags: british-english, slang, understanding

What is "He edges past the body" means in the last paragraph?

The living room. Alice hangs in the open doorway to the bedroom. Billy sits at the table with his
back to her. Screwed papers on the table and floor. He draws.
Billy (screws up a drawing) Cant do the feet right. They’re the wrong way. (Draws.) Why
don't the men come?

He picks up the handwritten list. Reads it. Puts it back on the table.
If I hadn't broken my crayons. Makes it hard. Won't break the new ones. (Draws.) The lady with
the chair’s got your face. (Picks up two drawings. Compares them.) Only hers is a puddle. (Puts
the drawings down. Draws.) P’raps she was your mother. Might’ve been.

He stops drawing. Stands. Goes towards the door.
’Scuse me, please.

He edges past the body. He touches it accidentally. It sways slightly. He goes into the other
room. Pause. He comes back. Squeezes past the body. Doesn’t touch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that *Alice hangs in the doorway* means literally that her hanged body is suspended from the top of the door frame. So, to walk through the doorway, Billy has to go sideways to try to avoid bumping into the body. To *edge* is to go carefully through a narrow gap, often sideways.